не работает prerender
столкнулся с проблемой того, что не всегда отрабатывает пререндер. Есть одна страница, на которой пререндер отрабатывает не всегда, иногда возвращает просто кусок оборванного кода, даже не доходя до body. Приложение на React.

на скриншоте 2 одинаковых запроса к страничке с userAgent yandex, должен отрабатывать пререндер и возвращать сгенерированную html страничку, но он это делает далеко не всегда. Но на других страничках такой проблемы нет, причем эта страничка отлична работает и проходит все тесты. В чем может быть причина? Заранее спасибо.

как запросы осуществляются?

посредством postman, с заголовком user-agent равном yandex. Просто делаю get запрос к странице приложения
